# VideoCapture returns an empty frame, but is a proper frame when saved to disk?

Tags: opencv, video-capture

```
video=cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')
success,frame=video.read()

# when the frame is printed it prints an array with all 0's
print(frame)

# But it is a proper image when saved to disk
cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg",frame)
```

The code prints a numpy array with 0's but a proper image when saved to the computer

Comment: it could be that the first frame is all 0? try using `cv2.imshow("frame", frame)` and `cv2.waitKey(0)` to see if it is a black window. Also, follow @Ozlu answer, and check if success is true, and it is also recommended to do `video.isOpened()` to check if the video was successfully opened

Comment: printing a numpy array will show an abbreviated representation. it may very well be that the corners of your picture are all 0 but the rest isn't. your conclusion can't be drawn from your observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the "frame is empty or not" and "does success return true?", and then you can save it in safe.

```
video=cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')
success,frame=video.read()

if(success and !(frame.empty())):      
    print(frame)
    cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg",frame)
else:
    print("empty frame")
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seems to be answering the question. It is just a check whether the frame is empty or not. For some situations, that empty frame may be an important frame that we don't want to skip. any way to resolve this issue?